# Calling API from URL params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using the newest version of React Router and want to get some optional parameters from the URL string.

There are two parameters, `appTypeId` and `submissionId`, they are both optional however they will either both exist or neither.

The URL looks like this `/appTypeId=1111&submissionId=9999`.

When I create my router I am declaring the path as follows:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/appTypeId=:appTypeId&submissionId=:submissionId?',
    element: <AppLayout />,
    id: 'root',
    loader: defaulNewAPIs,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <ReferralDetails status="new" />,
        // loader: defaulNewAPIs,
      },
    ],
  },
])
```

I want to leverage that `appTypeID` and `submissionId` to make an api call but I am getting a browser error telling me that there is no matching route.

First off, the entire URL string should be optional, so even if the URL string is empty content should render.

Second I am not sure why this URL `/appTypeId=1111&submissionId=9999` doesn't match the root element route.

Lastly, I am wondering if `useParams` is even the correct way to go about handling routes like this. I saw React Router has a `useSearchQuery` function and was thinking maybe they have a better way of handling routes like this.

Comment: Do you mean `?appTypeId=...&submissionId=...`? Query parameters are not part of the path.

Comment: Trying `?appTypeId=:appTypeId&submissionId=:submissionId` gives the same error.

Comment: Again they are _not part of the path_. Your path, with those query parameters, would just be `/`.

Comment: Got it. To be clear the path declaration in my browser router is `/` and the url to visit is `/?appTypeID=1111&submissionId=4444`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is what you can do**

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <AppLayout />,
    id: 'root',
    loader: defaulNewAPIs,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <ReferralDetails status="new" />,
        // loader: defaulNewAPIs,
      },
    ],
  },
])
```

if your URL will be `localhost:3000/?appTypeId=random4545&submissionId=your-submission-id`

We are component which will render root of page like /localhost:3000

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const ReferralDetails = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useSearchParams();
  
  funtion updateQueryParams () {
    setSearch({ appTypeId: "your-desired-updated-app-id", submissionId: "your- 
  desired-updated-updated-id" })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if(search.get("appTypeId") && !search.get("submissionId")){
      /* your api fetching if only appTypeID query param is available  */
    }
    if(!search.get("appTypeId") && search.get("submissionId")){ 
      /* your api fetching if only submissionId query param is available*/
    }

    if(search.get("appTypeId") && search.get("submissionId") ){
      /* your api fetching of if both query params are available */
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <p>appTypeId : {search.get("appTypeId")}</p>  {/* This p tag will return appTypeId : random4545  */}
      <p>submissionId: {search.get("submissionId")}</p> {/* This p tag will return submissionId: your-submission-id */}
      <button onclick={updateQueryParams}>update query params</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: @tdammon I also added useEffect that will help you in fetching data in relation with quey param